# Function-style macro with no-op if a condition is false

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

Suppose I have the following construct in multiple places in my code and want to make my code more legible:

```
#if HAVE_LIBFOOBAR
    foobar_func(data);
#endif
```

I was thinking of writing a function-style macro around this, which would handle the conditionals, making the occurrences in the code look like a regular function call:

```
    foobar_func_if_available(data)
```

If the condition is true, this would be replaced with a call to the actual function, else it would be a no-op.

Thus, something like:

```
#if HAVE_LIBFOOBAR
#define foobar_func_if_available(x) foobar_func(x)
#else
#define foobar_func_if_available(x) {}
#endif
```

Questions:

- Does `{}` work as a no-op? Is it safe from having unintended effects (such as being used in an unbracketed `if` statement)? If not, what would I use?
- Do I have to have two independent `#define`s wrapped in conditionals, or is there a way to do it the other way round (one `#define` with the conditionals inside the function-style macro)?

Edit: it has been suggested that this is a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/2703209), but in my opinion it is not: the other question asks “what is the problem solved with this construct”, mine is “what construct will solve my problem”. Indeed the other question has a possible solution to my problem, it does not cover all aspects of my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use apparently meaningless do-while and if-else statements in macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dummy function and make the #define point at it (conditionally):

---

```
#if HAVE_LIBFOOBAR
  #define foobar_func_if_available(x) foobar_func(x)
#else
  int dummy(int ignored)
  {
  return 0;
  }
  #define foobar_func_if_available(x) dummy(x)
#endif
```

---

Or just :

```
#define foobar_func_if_available(x) 0
```

Comment: In that case you could just do `int foobar_func(int u) { return 0; }` and skip the macro.

Comment: In fact my question was simplified: even with `HAVE_LIBFOOBAR` being false, the function might be available, I just do not want my code to use it. While skipping the macro would generally work, in my case it would not.

Comment: `((int)0)` would be a little safer. `0` is `((int)0)` but it's also the null pointer constant and an integer constant, which inadvertently greatly expands its uses over `((int)0)`.

Comment: The idea is to  emulate the signature of the original function (which was not shown) Thus, for `sin(x)` you could produce or return 0.0.

Comment: @wildplasser I understand. I'm just pointing out that if you want to emulate a function returning `int`, it's better done with `((int)0)` rather than `0`, as `0` can be used in many contexts where a non-const int expression couldn't be used.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot achieve it with a single `#define`.

You do not need `{}` as a no-op, you can define an empty expression in a number of ways:

```
#define foobar_func_if_available(x)
#define foobar_func_if_available(x) ;
#define foobar_func_if_available(x) do{}while(0)
```

There are circumstances where either of these may cause syntactic issues, but for void functions neither is likely to cause a problem - the solution breaks down for non-void functions however.

A better solution avoiding function-like macros altogether is to define the function body conditionally:

```
void foobar_func( int n )
{
    #if defined HAVE_LIBFOOBAR
       // do something
    #else
       // do nothing
    #endif
}
```

whether the empty function results in no code is a matter for the compiler and the optimisation level applied, but importantly the code will work syntactically in all situations where a call to `foobar_func()` is valid.  To worry about it being a no-op or not is probably sweating the small stuff.

Comment: This will cause problems if somebody forgets a semicolon: `foobar_func_if_available(x) something_else();` -- somebody who doesn't have LIBFOOBAR will see this compile successfully, but somebody who has it will see a compiler error. The traditional solution is a `do{}while(0)` with no trailing semicolon.

Comment: @RaymondChen : For multi-statement.function-like macros your advice holds, but for a single function call alias using a do-while would you prevent the use of  the macro in an expression.  However I have strictly answers the question regarding the NO-OP macro, the other definition is not in question and is not my code.

Comment: Leaving it empty would also prevent its use in an expression.

Comment: @wildplasser : alternative solutions to mine should be posted as answers not comments.  I am aware of the deficiencies of this solution, and welcome better suggestions.

Comment: True, best would be for the "no-LIBFOOBAR" case to specify a literal value of the same type as the return value of `foobar_func`.

Comment: @Clifford : Sorry.I was confused.

Comment: "*The `{ }` solution would result in syntactically invalid code*" - No, it would not (most of the time).

Comment: @RaymondChen : It was a terrible answer in any case - rewitten.  I have use the technique but only for debug code insertion that would make no sense in an expression.

Comment: @melpomene : True - anywhere a void function makes sense.  It is not a very general solution for functions that return a value.

Comment: I think the empty semicolon is bad -- it creates two empty statements if somebody writes `foobar_func_if_available(x);`. That messes up unbraced if-elses.

Comment: The `{}` notation doesn't work well in contexts such as `for (i = 10; --i > 0; foobar_func_if_available(i + 37)) { … }` — and neither does the `do { } while (0)` notation.  Using nothing, or `0` works better. Or you can ensure that the compiler inspects the arguments for validity by using `#define foobar_func_if_available(data) ((void)(data), 0)`; that expands the arguments and ignores them, but the result expression is 0 which can be converted to pointer or numeric value as required, or ignored.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : I don't disagree - every macro solution I offered attracted comments regarding deficiencies. I assumed that id `{}` is valid then teh function is `void` so would not be used like that as mentioned in my answer, it is not a general solution. Your solution is certainly better.  I leave you to propose it or leave it in the comment - I am not confident I'd get it right if I added it to my answer.  All macro solutions are bets avoided IMO.

Comment: @Jonathan it depends on whether the function returns a value, doesn't it? Generally (for void funcs) do..while is the canonical form because it replaces "true" function calls properly in all cases (in particular, does not create spurious empty statements).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Whether do..while is good. If the function returns a value it's probably better to substitute one.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I showed an example where the `do { … } while (0)` notation does not work — when the function is in the (first or) third term in a `for` loop control.  It doesn't matter whether it returns `void` or some value; the `do { … } while (0)` isn't going to work but an expression does work.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, I thought those were cases where a value is expected. I see. Interesting, first time I have seen that.

Answer (score 1):

Macros like `((int)0)` or `((void)0)` are probably the most flexible/safest no-op macros. They're flexible because you can use them 
in expressions (unlike `do{}while(0)`) and they don't break `if-else` like `{}` or `;` would.

Example of how `{}` (or `;`) macros break `if`-`else`:

```
#define foo() {}
if(1) foo(); else bar(); //syntax error because if(1) {}; else bar(); was pasted
```

If the macro should emulate an integer returning function, it's better to use a casted integer literal over a plain integer constant as integer constants (and especially zeros) are usable in more contexts (case labels, bitfield sizes, array sizes , null pointer constants) than non-const integer expressions.

You don't need to have two macros as in:

```
#if HAVE_LIBFOOBAR
    #define foobar_func_if_available(x) foobar_func(x)
#else
    #define foobar_func_if_available(x) ((void)0) /*if foobar_func returns void*/
#endif
```

You can put the condition inside the macro:

```
#define foobar_func_if_available(x) \
    (HAVE_LIBFOOBAR?foobar_func(x):((void)0))
```

Even a very dumb compiler should be able to optimize the constant conditional out.

But if you rely on an empty `HAVE_LIBFOOBAR` evaluating to `0` inside an `#if`, then the above won't work -- HAVE_LIBFOOBAR will need to be an integer.

(
You could do

```
#if !HAVE_LIBFOOBAR
    #undef HAVE_LIBFOOBAR
    #define HAVE_LIBFOOBAR 0
#endif
#define foobar_func_if_available(x) \
        (HAVE_LIBFOOBAR?foobar_func(x):((void)0))
```

to normalize an empty `HAVE_LIBFOOBAR` into `0` but unless you will reuse the now assured `HAVE_LIBFOOBAR`'s definedness, it seems like an unnecessary complication over the original two `foobar_func_if_available` macros.
)